# How to check string in json array

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

[console.log($scope.filteredOffers);](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWOu1.png)hi to all want to check string in json like that string coming form params now want to check in whole json and display only data which is related to that . Kindly check my code .. in other words want to display data according to the params which  is coming form url (which is coming ).

```
.controller('mixCtrl', function($scope,$http,$stateParams) {


     $http.get("http://tools.vcommission.com/api/coupons.php?apikey=e159f64e3dd49fddc3bb21dcda70f10c6670ea91aac30c7cb1d4ed37b20c45b8").then(function (response) {
      $scope.myData = response.data;
      $scope.offerName = ''; //set initially
      $scope.selectedIndex = -1;
      $scope.filteredOffers = [];
     // $scope.link1 = [];
     $scope.da = $stateParams.offer_name;
     var a =  $scope.da;
 console.log(a);

      $scope.filteredOffers = $scope.myData.filter(function(a) {
        for (var i=0;i<$scope.myData.length;i++)
        {
                $link =$scope.myData[i].offer_name;
            if (a==$link)
            {
                return a ;
                console.log(a );

            }

            //console.log(a );
            }
       // return offer.offer_name == $scope.da;
        console.log($scope.da);

      });
  });


  /*
 $scope.showData = function(offer_name, index) {
        $scope.offerName = offer_name;
      $scope.filteredOffers = $scope.myData.filter(function(offer) {
        return offer.offer_name == $scope.offerName;
      });
        $scope.selectedIndex = index;

      }*/
      $scope.dealopen = function(a){
            for (var i=0;i<$scope.myData.length;i++)
        {
            //console.log($scope.data[i].name);
            $link=$scope.data[i].name;
            console.log($link);
            if ($link==$a)
            {

            $window.open($link,"_self","location=yes"); 
            //console.log($a);
            }




        }



        }


})
```

Html

```
<div ng-repeat="offer in filteredOffers">
      <div class="couponCode">{{offer.coupon_code}}</div>
      <div class="couponTitle">{{offer.coupon_title}}</div>
      <div class="couponDescription">{{offer.coupon_Description}}</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are use the Array.filter() function wrongly!

Before :

```
$scope.filteredOffers = $scope.myData.filter(function(a) {
        for (var i=0;i<$scope.myData.length;i++)
        {
                $link =$scope.myData[i].offer_name;
            if (a==$link)
            {
                return a ;
                console.log(a );

            }

            //console.log(a );
            }
       // return offer.offer_name == $scope.da;
        console.log($scope.da);

      });
```

After (According to correct syntax) :

```
$scope.filteredOffers = $scope.myData.filter(function(a) {                    
            if (check condition)
            {
                return true ;// when true is returned the json held in a gets pushed into the filteredOffers array                
            }
            else{
                return false;//when false is returned, the json held in 'a' is ignored and not pushed into the filteredOffers array
            }      
      });
```

[Array.filter's Doc Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
But there is something wrong with the logic that you have used. If you can tell me exactly what you are trying to do, I might be able to help you out.

Comment: i want to display data on behalf of query string which is pass on /deal?offer_name   , that should be search on json file and display where they find the that parameter

Answer (score 0):

If you are processing json and arrays frequently in your application, then it's  better to integrate loadash or underscore in you application.

Add below code to your HTML before loading the controller file.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>`

After looking the response of `http://tools.vcommission.com/api/coupons.php?apikey=e159f64e3dd49fddc3bb21dcda70f10c6670ea91aac30c7cb1d4ed37b20c45b8`, below code will give you the array that matches the offer_name.

```
     $http.get("http://tools.vcommission.com/api/coupons.php?apikey=e159f64e3dd49fddc3bb21dcda70f10c6670ea91aac30c7cb1d4ed37b20c45b8").then(function (response) {

      $scope.filteredOffers = [];
      var offerName = $stateParams.offer_name;
      $scope.filteredOffers = _.filter(response.data, ["offer_name",offerName]);

      })
```

Comment: they giving syntax error SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Updated the answer. copy and paste this code inside your controller which will gives you what you are looking for.

Comment: data still not displayed

Comment: make sure that right value is coming in `$stateParams.offer_name`. Code is working perfectly well.

Comment: <div ng-repeat="offer in filteredOffers ">
      <div class="couponCode">{{offer.offer_name}}</div>
      
    </div>

Comment: $stateParams.offer_name give right value but how to display kindly check the ng-repeat

Comment: Please add `console.log(offerName)` and `console.log($scope.filteredOffers)` and check values are coming in the console.

Comment: Offer name giving the name but console.log($scope.filteredOffers) gives empty array check  the image ..

Comment: Failed to instantiate module underscore due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'underscore' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: I already inject script code on my index page but after adding the 'underscore ' in module it give me error